# What is the equivalent of systemd-analyze in CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, startup, init

systemd-analyze is the command to investigate time taken by each service during boot in CentOS 7. Is there a similar utility in CentOS 6 for doing this?

update: extending the question after Lucas' comment.

If there isn't such a direct way, any thoughts on using this method to compute total time taken by boot process:

t1 = time stamp shown by `last reboot`

t2 = last modified time of `/var/log/boot.log`

boot time = t2 - t1

Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: There isn't one, (See: https://askubuntu.com/a/628218/799594).

Comment: Use bootchart instead.